# Combine MySql query with Sphinx Query?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I have a site which uses a complex Sphinx query based on a complex Sphinx configuration. We empty the database each day and re-run the entire Sphinx configuration which takes hours.  The issue is that records which have been deleted from the database are still in the Sphinx index for that timeframe. Is there anyway to have the Sphinx Query somehow query Mysql to omit deleted IDs?

Answer (score 1):

If you can prepare a query which will return the IDs to omit from MySQL then you can use sql_query_killlist in another index and combine the main one with the new one via a distributed index and then when you query that it will suppress all the IDs returned by the query in the sql_query_killlist. Read about 'main + delta' schema and kill-lists in Sphinx's manual to learn more about that.